# Making Bread From Pizza Dough

Tags: bread, focaccia

My kitchen and I started to mess around and make loafs of bread from our pizza dough. Last night I loaded up a hotel pan with dough, and baked it for a little over an hour at 350. I let it rest and this morning I cut it open and there was a big ole air pocket in the middle of the loaf. We've had success before with using the dough as bread but this is the first time that this has happened. Did I proof it out too long? Use too much dough at once? Help!

Comment: How did you shape it?

Comment: to the shape of thel hotel pan

Comment: @Cory : the question isn't what shape, but *how* you shaped it.  Did you loosely set it in the pan, or did you work the air out of it, set it in the pan and then let it have a final rise?  I'm guessing you didn't treat it like foccaccia, where you specifically press all over it before baking to try to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Joe I did not press it. I took the dough from the fridge, placed it into the hotel pan and let it rest for a bit before placing it in the oven. I guess I should have worked the air out before putting it in the pan...

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it was probably the shaping that made the bubble.  Let the dough thaw enough so you can work it.  Then roll out and then start at one edge and roll up so there are no air pockets.  Tuck the ends under so the dough fits into the pan...having the ends contact the pan will support the dough while it rises.